# How to add back element after i remove it? using .removeAttr in Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, select

HI i have a example with me when if select the drop down list - price by recyclables a hidden field apppear but how can i when select the Service charger the hidden field disappear

I have try using .attr to add back but it seems to be not working

```js
$("#select-price-mode").change(function() {
  if (this.value === "Price By Recyclables") {
    $('.col').removeAttr('hidden');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col">
    <label for="select-price-mode" class="col-form-label">Price Mode</label>
    <select class="select-price-mode custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-price-mode" required>
      <option selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
      <option value="Price By Recyclables">Price By Recyclables</option>
      <option value="Service Charger">Service Charger</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <div class="col" hidden>
    <label for="select-payment-frequency" class="col-form-label">Payment Frequency</label>
    <select class="select-payment-frequency custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-payment-frequency" required>
      <option selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
    </select>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will solve your issue

```
$("#select-price-mode").change(function() {
  if (this.value === "Price By Recyclables") {
    $('.col').removeAttr('hidden');
  } else {
    $('.col').attr('hidden', '');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks oh mine i was trying to figure out 
but why does we need need to put the , '' behind

Comment: because for setting an attribute you need to pass both attr name and value. if you will do it without passing the second value the attr function will behave like getter and will return the value of attribute. you can read more about it here - https://api.jquery.com/attr/